# How to update the same row with condition in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Here's data

KeyID | Queue | Pay
65            1               0
60            2            0
58            3            1
57            4            1
55            5               0
54            6          0
53            7          1
50            8           1

if the data like this , I need a single MySql query to update it to be like below data table which update only Queue column.

KeyID | Queue | Pay
65            0               0
60            0            0
58            1            1
57            2            1
55            0               0
54            0          0
53            3          1
50            4           1

I have try this

update tabl1 
    set Queue = case when Pay = 0 then Queue=Queue-1 else Queue

But Queue number not look like this.

Please suggest.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You logic for update is not clear  ..  whay  65 and 60 are updated  to 0 and 58 and 57 to 1 and 2    .. you want update only the record  with pay = 0  or also the others ???'  .. seems that you want reassign the queue too

Comment: Queue seems rather redundant.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aqgEPYTfrWFjbWNc38qRrC/0

Comment: those updated to 0 because Pay=0. then 58,57 come to replace the position

Answer (score 0):

We can try joining to a subquery which computes the sequence:

```
UPDATE yourTable k1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT KeyID, rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.KeyID,
            (SELECT SUM(t2.Pay = 1) FROM yourTable t2
             WHERE t2.KeyID >= t1.KeyID) rn
        FROM yourTable t1
    ) t
) k2
    ON k1.KeyID = k2.KeyID
SET
    Queue = CASE WHEN Pay = 0 THEN 0 ELSE k2.rn END;
```

To see how the above logic is working, here is what the intermediate join table looks like:

```
KeyID | Queue | Pay | rn
65    | 1     | 0   | 0
60    | 2     | 0   | 0
58    | 3     | 1   | 1
57    | 4     | 1   | 2
55    | 5     | 0   | 2
54    | 6     | 0   | 2
53    | 7     | 1   | 3
50    | 8     | 1   | 4
```

That is, the innermost correlated subquery generates the queue sequence by counting the number of times `Pay` is 1.

Note that if you are using MySQL 8+, then there is a much simpler query using analytic functions:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Queue = CASE WHEN Pay = 0
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE SUM(Pay = 1) OVER (ORDER BY KeyID DESC) END;
```